What's the definition of a line integral on a possibly disconnected curve?
I'm trying to understand this paper, and I see this integral (page 2):
$$
\int_{B\ \cap\ \mathcal{C}} (1 - y)dy,
$$
where $\mathcal{C}$ is the curve given by $x = ye^{1-y}$ and $B$ can be any measurable set in $[0, 1]^2$.
This seems like a line integral, but the definition of a line integral that I know requires a differentiable parametrization of the curve. But

The direction of the curve is not specified, so should the integral be positive or negative? (I know it should be positive, but what's the mathematical reason?)
What if $B$ is such that $B \cap \mathcal{C}$ is not connected? No parametrization from an interval to $B \cap \mathcal{C}$ could be continuous, let alone differentiable.

I though of simply projecting $B \cap \mathcal{C}$ onto the $y$ axis and taking a
one dimensional Lebesgue integral over the projection, but according to this question the projected set may not be measurable.
So what is the definition of an integral like this?

Without specified orientation on the curve, this integral is undefined.

Presumably they mean the measure $|dy|$.  Who knows!
